# Solr MoreLikeThis handler

Tags: solr, solr4

I am trying to filter Solr results according to some property of the matched elements.

Let's say that the matched element has `price == 100`. I want to filter "similar" items which have a price greater than 80 and lower than 130 (like in `fq=price:[80 TO 130]`). Also, I don't know a priori that 100 is the price of the matched element, I only know that my query will always match a single document and I'd like to avoid querying Solr two times (one for retrieving price, the other to find similar items).

Is it possibile to achieve this with a function? I found the `frange` function and it seems promising, but I can't find a way to refer to the matched element's price property. Example: `price:{!frange l=0.8 u=1.3}div(price/$matched_element_price)`

Is there a way to achieve this result?

Comment: I don't follow, if you are sure your query "will always match a single document" what do you expect to achieve by adding additional fq?

Comment: The matched element is the one that acts as "blueprint" for the similar items. Similar items are, hopefully, much more than one and I need to further filter them.